# How to call a method from another class

Tags: java

There's an UNIQUE object which holds several informations about a person such as name, gender, two different time(startTime(10,20,30)  finishTime(20,30,0)) that a person have to deal with, and many more. My main concern is to call method (that does the job) from another class to access value of time stored in UNIQUE object. how do the call should be make?

```
double tmpDist = 3.1;
Race race1 = new Race("Annual TurkeyTown race1", tmpDist);

Runner al = new Runner("Smith", "Albert", 15, 'M', false);
String chip = "RD1234";
Time start = new Time(13, 0, 0);
Time end = new Time(14, 15, 0);
race1.addRunner(chip, al, start, end);
```

A race is a class and it stores array of runners. Runner is another class that holds information about runner. In addition to runner's details, race class is storing time information as well. There's a time class, which has methods that i wanted to use. Right now, i am trying to call a method inside of time class to access the different time of runners.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? What prevents you from calling some sort of `getTime()` method?

Comment: How do you store the Runner objects in the Race object? Your code example doesn't make clear how the relation between runner, chip, and times is stored inside Race (as Runner seems to only store personal info unrelated to the race).

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes you can call a method of a class from another class.

Say that you have an **instance** of `Unique` object. Then you can call the **public** methods that the class `Unique` defines as `aUniqueObject.getStartTime()`.

If you have defined static methods in `Unique` class then you may call them as `Unique.getStartTime()`.

Since your question lacks details, my answer may or may not apply.

Comment: I'm sure he knows this, but you may just want to clarify that the methods you are calling would have to be `public`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple constructors to a one class. It will look like this.

```
class Race{
  String racertopic ="";
  Double tmpDist;
  String Runnername=""; 

 Race(String s,Double q){
  racertopic = s;
  tmpDist = q;
}



Race(al.fiirstname(),al.lastname(),al.ag`e(),al.gender,al.state)
{
  racertopic = al.fiirstname();//complete others like this

}

}
```

I explained as i understand your question. If you could show other classes it will be a help to answer.